# Navigation properties not loading in self-referencing relation

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I've model `Category` that has a self-referencing relation:

```
public class Category
{
    public Category()
    {
        this.Childs = new HashSet<Category>();
    }

    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

    public HashSet<Category> Childs { get; set; }

    //... other useless properties
}
```

Relation configuration is defined in context:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOptional(c => c.Parent)
            .WithMany(c => c.Childs)
            .HasForeignKey(m => m.ParentId);
```

I've also generic `Repository` that includes methods:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetAll()
{
    return this.dbSet.ToList();
}

public IQueryable<T> AsQuerable()
{
    return this.dbSet.AsQueryable();
}
```

And now very strange behaviour occurs. I call a method:

```
var categoriesEntites =
        this.catogries.AsQuerable()
                      .Where(cat => cat.ProjectId == projectId 
                                    && cat.ParentId == null)
                      .ToList();
// this.categories is of type `Repository<Category>`
```

In the result, `Childs` are not loaded..:
[image: Usual case]

But when I call `GetAll` before:

```
this.catogries.GetAll();
var categoriesEntites =
        this.catogries.AsQuerable()
                      .Where(cat => cat.ProjectId == projectId 
                                    && cat.ParentId == null)
                      .ToList();
```

Suddenly navigation properties works..
[image: With GetAll]

I've used such an approach many times before, and I have never had such a problem..
Some ideas? `LazyLoading` is turned on of course..

To make things more strange, I've other self-referencing entity (that is build in exactly the same way) and there is no such a bug.

**BTW. Sorry** for typo mistake in nav property, it should be `Children` of course, not `Childs`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `ToList()` in your `GetAll()` method, EF loads the entire table and will store those entities locally. This is why they appear loaded when you perform this query:

```
var categoriesEntites =
    this.catogries.AsQuerable()
                  .Where(cat => cat.ParentId == null)
                  .ToList();
```

If you look at the generated SQL for the above query, it actually only fetches categories where `ParentId` is null:

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CategoryId] AS [CategoryId], 
    [Extent1].[ParentId] AS [ParentId]
    FROM [dbo].[Categories] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ParentId] IS NULL
```

The child collection isn't fetched even after inspecting the collection in VS debugger (triggers lazy loading) because its already loaded and stored locally by EF.

If you want to get child objects without using `ToList()` ( or `GetAll()` ), use the `virtual` keyword on your child collection. This is a requirement for lazy loading and will fetch when that child collection is accessed, by code or VS debugger.

```
public virtual HashSet<Category> Childs { get; set; }
```